# Android JSON parsing using the Gson Library

Tags: java, json, gson

i want to parse the following data using the Gson library.

```
{
    "claimTypeList": [
        "Dental",
        "Outpatient",
        "Hospitalisation/Surgery"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("claimTypeList")
@Expose
private List<String> claimTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
*
* @return
* The claimTypeList
*/
public List<String> getClaimTypeList() {
return claimTypeList;
}

/**
*
* @param claimTypeList
* The claimTypeList
*/
public void setClaimTypeList(List<String> claimTypeList) {
this.claimTypeList = claimTypeList;
}

}
```

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 2):

Create a model class like this

```
public class Claims {
    List<String> claimTypes; 
}
```

And here convert your string to object

```
String data = "{\"claimTypeList\":[\"Dental\",\"Outpatient\",\"Hospitalisation/Surgery\"]}"
Claims c = new Claims();
c = new Gson().FromJson(data, Claims.class);
```

hope this may help.